# What is the difference between the “Google+ API” and the “Google+ API (Sign-in)”?

Tags: google-plus

What is the difference between the “Google+ API” and the “Google+ API (Sign-in)”?

Answer (score 0):

[The Google+ API (Sign-In)](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) seems to be suited at allowing a developer to integrate the Google login in into their application to allow their app to have an OAuth token to interact with Google services.

[The Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) on the other hand is just the Google API that allows access to a users Google+ API data, you will need an authentication token to access this data.

Answer (score 0):

The two different quota buckets refer to two different subsets of the API that are available. You can see https://developers.google.com/+/api/#quota for the details, but broadly speaking:

The Sign-In portion applies to methods that specifically need the *plus.login* scope. These include [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get), [people.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list), [moments.insert](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert), [moments.remove](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/remove) and [moments.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/list). This is a much larger quota to encourage people to use these methods.

The other, more broad, bucket is for all other methods, including those for Activities and Comments and a few others for People.